# Cómo Conseguir Con Map Este Valor En ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fetch, map

Soy un novato autodidacta y estoy intentando realizar un pequeño proyecto usando una API, en este caso "https://bluelytics.com.ar/#!/api". Mi problema es que intento mapear el useState utilizado (cotización) y no logro ver cómo acceder a, por ejemplo, el valor de venta del blue.

```
const Cotizacion = () => {

const [cotizacion, setCotizacion] = useState([])

const getCotizacion = () =>{
    const pedido = fetch('https://api.bluelytics.com.ar/v2/latest')
    pedido.then((respuesta)=>{
        console.log(respuesta)
        return respuesta.json()
    })
    .then((respuesta)=>{
        console.log(respuesta)
        console.log(respuesta.blue.value_buy)
        setCotizacion(respuesta)
    })
}

useEffect(()=>{
    getCotizacion()
},[])
```

esto sería el cuerpo de mi código. Como ven, hay dos console log, uno en respuesta, cuyo resultado es:
"{oficial: {…}, blue: {…}, oficial_euro: {…}, blue_euro: {…}, last_update: '2023-03-31T17:30:31.977658-03:00'}
blue
:
{value_avg: 393, value_sell: 395, value_buy: 391}
blue_euro
:
{value_avg: 422.5, value_sell: 425, value_buy: 420}
last_update
:
"2023-03-31T17:30:31.977658-03:00"
oficial
:
{value_avg: 211.5, value_sell: 216, value_buy: 207}
oficial_euro
:
{value_avg: 228, value_sell: 233, value_buy: 223}
[[Prototype]]
:
Object"

Dado esto, yo asumo, como hago en un console.log con notacion de punto que debería poder acceder al valor indicado. Hago "console.log(respuesta.blue.value_buy)" y el resultado es 391.

Ahora, de vuelta al código, mi return es:

```
  return (
<div>
    <h1>Cotización</h1>
    {
        cotizacion.length > 0 &&
        cotizacion.map((iteracion)=>{
            return (
                <div key={iteracion.id}>
                    <p>{iteracion.blue.value_buy}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
</div>
```

)
}

Pero no aparece nada en pantalla salvo el h1 y en consola no figura ningún error. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Cómo puedo acceder a ese valor o, en definitiva, a los valores contenidos en lo que obtengo de mi fetch?

Desde ya muchas gracias y perdón las molestias.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, sugiero iniciar la depuración revisando si la `respuesta` es un arreglo, coloca este console en el `then` antes de setear estado:  `console.log(Array.isArray(respuesta))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la respuesta es tal como pones, el map no te vale, ya que es para iterar un array y tu lo que obtienes es un objeto. Si quieres acceder a la propiedad blue, deberías hacer:

```
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Cotización</h1>
        <p>{cotizacion?.blue?.value_buy}</p>
    </div>)
```

el `?` es para que antes de tener valor cotizacion no de error. una vez que termine la peticion de la api y tenga valor se mostrara.

Tambien deberías inicializar la variable cotización con el mismo formato que devuelve la llamada o con `null` o `undefined`.

```
const [cotizacion, setCotizacion] = useState({});
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Funciona perfecto así!